# Update pillar data in custom module?

Tags: salt-stack

I would like to update the pillar data in a custom module.

Background: I would like to set some default values.

This would make the code in jinja simpler, since I could use one place to create defaults (in custom module) and N conditionless usages of the pillar data (in jinja).

For example, up to now the code looks like this (at several places):

```
{% if pillar.database_replication|default(False) %}
```

I would like to set the default in a custom module.

Then this would be enough:

```
{% if pillar.database_replication %}
```

My goal is to make sls files simpler.

I use salt version 2019.2.0.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you can do is have a 'defaults' pillar file, which is loaded before all others.

Something like this in pillar top.sls

```
base:
  '*':
     - defaults

# rest of pillar to load
```

Then you can have in defaults.sls

```
# default pillars for all minions
database_replication: False
```

Then:

- if a minion do not have a specific value: you get the default one
- if a minion have a specific value, it's set after loading the 'defaults' so it overrides it, and you get the minion specific value